# How to ignore empty values when passing a ViewModel (object) via Ajax to an MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

In the following `view` I'm passing an Object (ViewModel) to controller. It works fine if user enters all the values in the form. The sample Requested URL with `querystring` generated via LINQ query is as follows:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:50507/OrdCtrl/OrdAction?OrdYear=2016&OrderNumber=CE123&OrderName=testOrder&hasOrdered=true&_=1489509308855
```

But if the user skips entering one value in the search form, say, `orderName` the user gets the expected error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I think the above error occurs since the generated Requested URL is missing the parameter value for `orderName` as shown below:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:50507/OrdCtrl/OrdAction?OrdYear=2016&OrderNumber=CE123&OrderName=&hasOrdered=true&_=1489509308855
```

**Question**: In the `dataObj` inside Ajax call below, how can we skip the input parameters if their values are empty strings - so the generated querystring does not include those parameters. **NOTE**: This is a search form and users are allowed to search based only on the values they enter inside form.

**TestViewModel:**

```
public class UsetListViewModel
{
    public int OrdYear { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public bool hasOrdered { get; set; }
}
```

**View**:

```
@model TestProj.Models.TestViewModel

....<!--Some html here-->

<div>
    <form asp-controller="OrdCtrl" asp-action="OrdAction" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="OrdID" />
        <div ><button type="button" id="SearchBtn">Search</button></div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="searchResults"></div>     


@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#SearchView').on('click', '#SearchBtn', function (event) {

                var dataObj = {
                    OrdYear: $('#yearID').val(),
                    OrderNumber: $('#OrdNumb').val(),
                    OrderName: $('#OrdName').val(),
                    hasOrdered : $('[name=hasOrd]:checked').val()
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("OrdAction", "OrdCtrl")',
                    data: dataObj,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                            $('#searchResults').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        alert('jqXHR.statusCode');
                    }
                });
            });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just don't populate the values in dataObj in your javascript unless the form field values are set.

so updating the declaration of dataObj to something like:

```
var dataObj = {};
if ($('#yearID').val() !== '') {
    dataObj.OrdYear = $('#yearID').val();
}
if ($('#OrdNumb').val() !== '') {
    dataObj.OrderNumber = $('#OrdNumb').val();
}
... etc ...
```

Should remove the empty query parameters on the GET request.

Comment: the controller should check for an be able to handle null values for one or maybe all of the various search params. you might consider using the PredicateBuilder class to dynamically add criteria to your linq query depending on what values actually get sent to the controller.

Comment: Your solution works but there was a problem when the `dataObj` was sent to the controller with, say, `OrdNum` as null. The LINQ query in that case was throwing well known error: `NullReferenceException`. To remedy that I had to use `qry = _context.Orders.Where(o => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myModel.OrdNum) || p.OrdNum == myModel.OrdNum)`. But, to be fair, you answered to what I asked (thank you).